# Copiar carpeta de un servidor local con php

Tags: php, cmd

Buen día, soy capaz de copiar los archivos contenidos en una carpeta situada en un servidor local a mi pc con el símbolo del sistema (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se podría hacer lo que estoy haciendo en cmd con código php ?

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejecutar ese comando directamente con, por ejemplo [`system()`](http://php.net/system)? El principal problema que veo es que el servicio apache correrá con usuario que tiene privilegios locales pero no remotos. ¿Y con [`opendir()`](http://php.net/opendir) te deja abrirlo o te da problema de permisos? La ruta de origen puedes llamarla internamente en PHP como `'//192.168.2.3/Archivos/'` o bien tendrás que escapar cada contra barra de la siguiente manera: `'\\\\192.168.2.3\\Archivos\\'`.

Comment: Si respondes a mi pregunta no olvides nombrarme con `@OscarGarcia` para que me llegue una notificación. La tarea se puede implementar completamente en PHP pero requiere esa prueba previa para determinar si necesitas modificar permisos o usuario efectivo del servicio.

Comment: Cuando dices servidor local, te refieres a que estas trabajando sobre tu red lan??. En ese caso si es posible, incluso usando el mismo comando CMD. Revisa la documentacion de PHP de la funcion exec. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php

Comment: si los datos que quieres copiar estan compartidos en la red (tiene pinta de que estes usando samba internamente) no se necesita utilizar un apache para correr el programa de php que te haga dicha copia, seria el mismo interprete de php el que tendria que ejecutarse con los permisos del usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría conectar por FTP a un servidor remoto y hacer operaciones en él mediante las funciones para operaciones `ftp`  [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.ftp.php)  puedes encontrar más información.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo un ejemplo sencillo para descargar un archivo:

```
<?php
// Define la conexión al servidor
$ftp_server = "ftp.ejemplo.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("No se puede conectar al servidor $ftp_server");
//Comprueba usuario y contraseña del
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

//Define las variables donde se almacenarán los archivos
$local_file = "local.zip";
$server_file = "server.zip";

// Descarga los archivos del servidor
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Descargado correctamente en  $local_file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error al descargar $server_file.";
  }

// Cerrar conexión
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, ¿como colocaría en $ftp_server si el servidor es local? ¿Sería algo asi como $ftp_server= "192.168.2.3"?

Answer (score 1):

Con exec de PHP ejecutas el comando de MS-DOS, **exec (comando,variable de salida);**

Tal como lo harías con la consola, pruebalo y nos comentas.

```
<?php

$copiar = exec("xcopy *.txt C:\dir-destino /Y",$salida);
echo "Resultado > $copiar <br>";

//la variable salida es un array

$tot=count($salida);
echo "=== Salida ===";

for($i=0;$i<=$tot;$i++){
echo "[$i] > $salida[$i] <br>";

}
?>
```